# What is better to use when querying a large but fixed number of structs - an array or a mapping?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, evm, storage

In general, it seems as though mappings generally result in cheaper operations. What about when the number of elements are fixed (say, 20K) and setting the elements only ever occur once?

Would a mapping still prove cheaper? What if iteration is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep down, an array is a mapping with range-bound keys. The most expensive aspect is the SSTORE operations and SLOAD operations which are the same in both cases.

An array has additional steps (operations, so gas) to check that row is not out of range.

A dynamic array is significantly more expensive because each push overwrites the length and range checks read from storage rather than compiled bytecode, i.e. additional SSTORE and SLOAD.

Hope it helps

Comment: did you mean SLOAD by the way? And could you expand on what you meant by them being the same in both cases?